# Can you burn a CD using a DVD-R?

Tags: dvd, music, burning, cd-burning

Is it possible to burn a CD using a DVD-R and have it play the music on a CD player? Or, for the obtuse:

Is it possible to take a pre-recorded CD in [Audio CD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_disc#Audio_CD) format and copy the content to a [DVD-R disc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DVD-R) so the copied disc will play in a standard CD player.

Comment: Are you asking if you can burn a CD using a DVD *burner*?  Or burn music to a DVD-R *disc* as if it were a CD and play it in a CD player?

Comment: @SandyGifford Or, as the question is currently stated, he might for all we know be asking if he could use the DVD-R disc itself to burn music to a CD-R. Not exactly great wording.

Comment: Why has a question this unclear been voted up instead of being closed?

Comment: I think it's about whether a DVD'R is actually a source of ignition... And if you could create flame from the DVD'R, the OP still wants the original functionality to remain. In the same way in the UK, the warnings on matches indicate fire can only kill children, the OP wants the same restrictive (or intelligent) type of flame to only seek CD's, destroy them so presumably DVD can rule supreme.

Comment: The reason why this has been upvoted may be that people have wondered about if you could make an "Audio DVD".

Answer (score 9):

No.

A standard, run-of-the-mill discount-store-sourced CD player will only play CDs, CD-Rs, or CD-RWs.

DVDs would not work in a CD player even if you could force it to burn to the DVD in "Red Book Audio" format (which is the format a CD's audio is in on the disc).  The physical format is not compatible.

A standard called "DVD Audio" was created that would have been an "upgrade" from CDs as far as audio is concerned but it never took off.  I've not listened to music in disc form for well over a decade so I've never heard of the disc DVD-Audio players @Keltari speaks of.  This would only work in a DVD-Audio compatible player (physically it's a DVD) and not a standard dirt-cheap standard CD player.

Sony's SACD was also another "next generation" audio disc standard that isn't terribly popular.  Those are something else entirely.

Comment: I do think some cheap DVD players I have might play them. Not entirely sure of the point of that though ;p

Comment: @JourneymanGeek:  The point is that you can only store 80 minutes of music on a single CD.  I was wondering about this thing myself and have tried to burn an "Audio DVD" to play in the car, I don't want to swap discs while driving.

Comment: I mean, DVD audio was supported on cheap players. However, a higher fidility format on a cheap player is odd. In this day and age, as of 2017, many car audio players do handle digital formats natively anyway...

Answer (score 7):

**NO, not possible**

The difference between the DVD-R and DVD-RW is the presence of dedicated read and write laser circuitry .For further reading follow the [link](http://electronics.howstuffworks.com/dvd-player.htm). Below are some of the part from the [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_disc_drive)

> On read only media (ROM), during the manufacturing process the groove, made of pits, is pressed on a flat surface, called land. Because the depth of the pits is approximately one-quarter to one-sixth of the laser's wavelength, the reflected beam's phase is shifted in relation to the incoming reading beam, causing mutual destructive interference and reducing the reflected beam's intensity. This is detected by photo diodes that output electrical signals.
>
> A recorder encodes (or burns) data onto a recordable CD-R, DVD-R, DVD+R, or BD-R disc (called a blank) by selectively heating parts of an organic dye layer with a laser[citation needed]. This changes the reflectivity of the dye, thereby creating marks that can be read like the pits and lands on pressed discs. For recordable discs, the process is permanent and the media can be written to only once. While the reading laser is usually not stronger than 5 mW, the writing laser is considerably more powerful. The higher writing speed, the less time a laser has to heat a point on the media, thus its power has to increase proportionally. DVD burners' lasers often peak at about 200 mW, either in continuous wave and pulses, although some have been driven up to 400 mW before the diode fails.
>
> For rewritable CD-RW, DVD-RW, DVD+RW, DVD-RAM, or BD-RE media, the laser is used to melt a crystalline metal alloy in the recording layer of the disc. Depending on the amount of power applied, the substance may be allowed to melt back (change the phase back) into crystalline form or left in an amorphous form, enabling marks of varying reflectivity to be created.
>
> Double-sided media may be used, but they are not easily accessed with a standard drive, as they must be physically turned over to access the data on the other side.
>
> Double layer (DL) media have two independent data layers separated by a semi-reflective layer. Both layers are accessible from the same side, but require the optics to change the laser's focus. Traditional single layer (SL) writable media are produced with a spiral groove molded in the protective polycarbonate layer (not in the data recording layer), to lead and synchronize the speed of recording head. Double-layered writable media have: a first polycarbonate layer with a (shallow) groove, a first data layer, a semi-reflective layer, a second (spacer) polycarbonate layer with another (deep) groove, and a second data layer. The first groove spiral usually starts on the inner edge and extends outwards, while the second groove starts on the outer edge and extends inwards.

Comment: now this doesn't explain why it won't work. I think the answer was better with the wiki dump, I like the format of the answer with all the links but I think you should have still included the wiki, maybe a shortened version,  like just the parts that explain why this wouldn't work

Comment: I liked they way you added the links though too, I think those should also be in there

Comment: Either properly cite your source material or it will be deleted for plagiarism

Comment: @ random : Those wiki notes will be useful for other users to quickly understand the facts. So please don't delete it.

Answer (score 5):

the layering of a DVD is different than that of a CD

> One of the first differences between CDs and DVDs to note is in the amount of data storage that is possible with each device. The typical DVD will provide in the range of seven times the capacity that is available on a compact disk. DVDs make use of a series of recording layers and also store data on both sides of the device, which makes a big difference in the storage capacity. The older technology associated with the CD does not allow for these same applications.

[What is the Difference Between CDs and DVDs?](http://www.wisegeek.com/what-is-the-difference-between-cds-and-dvds.htm)

No, it would not work.

The Video on [Video:DVD vs. CD: How Are They Different?](http://video.about.com/netforbeginners/DVD-vs--CD---How-Are-They-Different-.htm) shows the Difference in the layering pretty well at about 1 minute in

a CD is Layered like this

- Polycarbonate Layer
- Data Layer
- Metal Layer
- Protecting Laquer
- Surface Layer

a DVD is Layered like this

- Polycarbonate Layer
- Data Layer
- Metal Layer
- Polycarbonate Layer

the Grooves or Pits on  DVD are narrower and not as Deep as they are on a CD, so the Reflection is different when trying to read a DVD from a CD player.

Comment: The layering looks irrelevant, they both have polycarbonate-data-metal.  Does it really matter what comes after the metal?   But +1 for mentioning the reflections.

Comment: I looked at this and thought that it was the other way around, but I hear what you are saying, but the grooves are already in the disc before you try to record anything on it.  the grooves are different between the two. otherwise I agree with you, they are not all that different, @OskarSkog

Comment: I realized one thing about the first polycarbonate layer, it's much thinner on DVDs and I guess that's one of the reasons the reflections are different.

Answer (score 2):

You *can* burn a CD ISO, or write a CD data to DVDs...

However, CD player lasers operate on a different frequency than DVD lasers.  Not to mention DVD record at a higher density than CDs.  A true CD player would not be able to read the disc.

If the CD player was also a DVD player, then it should be able to read the disc.

Note, there are CD players out there that can read DVD audio.  These should be able to read a CD burned to a DVD, as they are really DVD players.

Answer (score 1):

While the data can be written, the density of the data is very different between DVD and CD. It's impossible to burn a DVD at CD density (as far as I know), so unless you have a DVD player you are using for CD content, this will not work.